# How to get RSAParameters Exponent size 3 bytes in Xamarin?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, xamarin, xamarin.ios, c#-2.0

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
RSAParameters rsaParameters = rsaProvider.ExportParameters(true);
byte[] byteArray = rsaParameters.Exponent;
System.Console.Write("byteArray Size ## " + byteArray.Count());
```

Output : byteArray Size ## 1

If we are using the same line of code in .net dll it gives us 3 bytes but in Xamarin it gives us 1 byte. 
Please let us know if there is any alternate for this.